# web service are very slow when several users are connected to the application

Tags: python, flask, mariadb

I am developing a flutter app using flask as back end framework and mariabd as database

Trying to reduce web service time response of ws:

```
 1- open the connexion at the begining of ws
 2- Execute queries
 3-close connexion to database before returnning the response
```

Here is an exemple of my code archi:

```
@app.route('/ws_name', methods=['GET'])
def ws_name():

     cnx=db_connexion()

     try:
         id_lanparamguage = request.args.get('param')
         result = function_execute_many_query(cnx,param)
     except:
         cnx.close()
         return jsonify(result), 200

     response = {}
     cnx.close()

     return jsonify(result), 200
```

db_connexion is my function that handle connecting to database

The probleme is  when only one user is connecting to the app (use ws) the time response is perfect

but if 3 users (as exemple) are connected th time response is up from millisecond to 10 seconds

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you have a problem with many requests sharing the same thread. Read https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/local/ for how the local context works and why you need werkzeug to manage your local context in an WSGI application.

You would want to do something like:

```
     from werkzeug.local import LocalProxy


     cnx=LocalProxy(db_connexion)
```

I also recommend closing your connextion in a function decorated by @app.teardown_request
See https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Flask.teardown_request